# How to use Git commit count in TeamCity build number format

Tags: github, teamcity

I would like to display the commit count number, as seen on my repository within GitHub, in TeamCity's build number format field. Currently, the Build Number Format field within General Settings in my TeamCity setup is set to **3.4.%build.counter%**. This is showing the major and minor version followed by the auto-incrementing build number.

I would like to take this a step further and show the commit number on my repository in GitHub. So, it would be something like this: **1.2.%git_commit_number%.%build.counter%**.

My question is, how do I pass this **%git_commit_number%** to the Build Number Format field? I know the command `git rev-list --count HEAD` returns this commit count number but I am not sure how to pass it to this field. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found a solution to this.. Create a new PowerShell build step in TeamCity that points directly to the path of the Git executable on the server. The add your Git arguments accordingly. Example below -

```
$git_log_result=cmd /c '"%env.GIT_HOME%bin\git.exe" log --grep="kerbol" --pretty=oneline -5'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add specific build step, that will use TeamCity build script interaction.
Example build step code on Powershell:

```
$build_number = "%build.number%" # or build.counter
$git_commit_number = git rev-list --count HEAD
Write-Host "##teamcity[buildNumber '$build_number.$git_commit_number']"
```

For linux agents use 'echo'